# Hashing Session ID

Tags: authentication, session-management

For my app I use redis as a session store. Is it safe to store the session id without using a hash function? If I should use a hash function, the client would receive the cookie with the raw or the hashed session id?

Comment: Hashing is on way and once hashed you won't be able to retrieve the original value by design. If you are worried about the confidentiality then better would be to encrypt the session id. But IMO it's ok to have short lived session ID in plain text in the memory.

Comment: What is your goal in hashing it?

Comment: If your session id has been generated by a random function have no sense to make a hash, however if your session id is very long and you want to make it small then you can hash it but probably will be a good idea to review your session id generator function in order to generated small

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most important thing is that your session ID's are unguessable, e.g. long and random. Make sure you are doing it right there first.

Since session ID's are relatively short lived, there is not the same need to hash them as for passwords. Also, while passwords are often reused, session ID's are not. My guess is that most systems do not hash them. But especially if you have long sessions (e.g. for a "remember me" functionality), it makes some sense to hash them. Think about how likely it is that the content of your Redis server somehow gets into the wrong hands during that time frame?

If you do hash them, you don't need anything more fancy than a simple round of SHA3 or similar. Since your session ID is high entropy (see my first point), brute forcing should not be possible. And you should absolutely send the unhashed ID to the client. If you send the hash, you get a pass-the-hash problem where an attacker who steals the hash can use it directly as the session ID without having to crack it.

Comment: To my understanding session IDs often not being hashed is not due to their lifetime. If the list of session IDs is leaked, they still grant access to everyone that is currently logged on, which is bad enough. However, that is only the case if they can use these session IDs, but if the method to send session IDs is for example with cryptographically signed cookies then they can't do anything with these session IDs since they don't (yet) know how to sign the cookie and can't forge one. That's the reason I believe why many don't implement it, it's not needed if you use cookies and sign them.

Answer (score 4):

If done correctly, hashing a session token can protect sessions from limited forms of insider attacks or leaks. (A malicious employee, perhaps, or SQL injection.)

A person who gains read access to the database table storing raw session IDs, on the other hand, would be able to hijack any active session. An attacker would not be able hijack sessions if all they are given is the hash of a session token.

<sub>*(That's assuming that secret token values were generated by a secure RNG, processed with a preimage resistant hash function, and that you have no exploitable implementation errors.)*</sub>

Hashing the token would ***not*** do anything to protect against an adversary who could eavesdrop on HTTP requests. Nor against someone who could access plaintext secrets in RAM, swap space, logs, or caches.

Hashing does not, at all, prevent someone with write access from hijacking accounts by inserting their own session-token hashes into the session table.

The client sends the raw session token. Providing the hash of a session token does not prove that you know the secret token value.

If you only store the hash and you erase the raw token from memory as soon as it's no longer needed, then it *should* be impossible for an attacker to find out the raw session token without targetting the client.

<sub>That "should" carries several heavy caveats. I've already mentioned enough to give you an idea of what kind of challenges are involved. I skipped an explanation of direct attacks on the RNG, side channel attacks, constant-time binary-safe hash digest comparison, and other topics. But, in principle, storing the hash is at least as safe as storing the raw value.</sub>